# Firebase: How do I write to Realtime Database only if the write to Cloud Storage was successful?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

The first function will write to Firebase Cloud Storage and if there are no errors, I want to write to Realtime Database. Both of these are "fire and forget" functions, but I only want to run the second one if the first one successfully uploaded the file to Cloud Storage.

```
void sendFile(ChatData file, String filepath, String filename) async {
    saveToCloudStorage(filepath, filename);

    //If the aformentioned function was successful, run the next one
    saveToRTDB(file);
  }

void saveToCloudStorage(String filepath, String filename) async {
    _firebaseStoragePath = MyAppStorageDir + filename;
    
    File file = File(filepath);

    try {
      await _firebaseStorage
          .ref(_firebaseStoragePath)
          .putFile(file);
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }

void saveToRTDB(ChatData file) async {
    _messagesRef.push().set(file.toJson());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `saveToCloudStorage` swallows any exceptions that are raised, there is no way for the caller to determine whether the call succeeded or failed.

If you don't want to expose what error might have happened, you can return an (async) boolean:

```
Future<bool> saveToCloudStorage(String filepath, String filename) async {
  _firebaseStoragePath = MyAppStorageDir + filename;
  
  File file = File(filepath);

  try {
    await _firebaseStorage
        .ref(_firebaseStoragePath)
        .putFile(file);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then in the caller:

```
saveToCloudStorage(filepath, filename).then(() {
  saveToRTDB(file);
})
```

Comment: Ah ok this makes sense. It's saying that I can't have the function be `void` so I switched it to `Future<bool>` instead. It's also saying that the last `return true;` line is "dead code", so I removed it. Thanks!!

Comment: Wait sorry, it's saying this error, pointing to the `saveToRTDB` line:
`The argument type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(void)'`

Comment: Yeah, that last line is not dead code as far as I know. ;-)

Comment: I put it back. Do you know why I might be getting the argument type error?